# Jquery mobile theme not detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I've just created [this theme](http://pastebin.com/hSbNkgfX) with the [jquery mobile theme rooler](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/), and included it in my page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themename.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="container" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
  <div class="title" data-role="header">Title</div>
  <div class="box" data-role="content">
  Content
  </div>  <div class="footer" data-role="footer">
Some other content
  </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the default theme is displayed:
[image: Screen of output]
The chrome console isn't reporting any errors.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your theme which I'm presuming is `themename.min.css` below `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css`. The way themes work in CSS is usually by overriding selectors, such as class names. If two stylesheets apply styles to the same selector, the last defined instance is the one that's used. Currently, you're defining your theme and overriding it with the main jQuery theme. Reverse the order and your problem should be fixed. Below would be an optimal loading scenario.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themename.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**For CSS:**

1. Load the default jQuery Mobile Theme
2. Load the jQuery Mobile Icon overrides
3. Load your custom theme `thememain.min.css`

In addition, it's wise to move the JavaScript below the CSS files. CSS Files are downloaded in parallel whereas JavaScript files are usually downloaded and parsed one at a time.